# How to interpret jeprof output

Tags: java, memory-leaks

Recently I came across some java related memory leaks (continuously decreasing server-free memory and finally getting RAM warning which we have set up using nagios) and I did an investigation and found that the memory leak is not related to the heap ara. But still tomcat process's memory consumption keeps growing.
[server memory graph - 7 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZOjE.png)

- Did a heap memory analysis and nothing found in there ( if I run `jcmd <pid> GC.run` heap memory usage drops to around 200MB from 2.8GB). [heap memory graph - 7 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyL5w.png)
- Checked metaspace area and other memory areas related to the JVM as per the discussion on this video and post.

  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=2483&v=c755fFv1Rnk&feature=youtu.be
  - https://github.com/jeffgriffith/native-jvm-leaks/blob/master/README.md

Finally, I added jemalloc to profile native memory allocation, and here is some of the output that I got.

- [ouptput 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGsGC.gif)
- [ouptput 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZBXt.gif)

But I couldn't interpret this output and I'm not sure whether this output is correct or not.

And also I have a doubt regarding whether that jeprof is working with oracle JDK.

Could you please help me on this?

Additional info:

- server memory: 4GB
- Xmx: 3072M (recently we changed to this and earlier it was 2048M. but the memory behavior is similar on both occasions)
- Xms: 3072M (recently we changed to this and earlier it was 2048M. but the memory behavior is similar on both occasions)
- javac -version: jdk1.8.0_72
- java version:
  "1.8.0_72"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)
- jemelloc configs:

  - jemelloc version: https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/releases/download/5.2.1/jemalloc-5.2.1.tar.bz2
  - export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.so
  - export MALLOC_CONF=prof:true,lg_prof_interval:31,lg_prof_sample:17,prof_prefix:/opt/jemalloc/jeprof-output/jeprof
- My application is running on a tomcat server in an ec2 instance (only one application running on that server).

Comment: @Kayaman yes, the server's free memory decreasing continuously (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZOjE.png), and we have set an alert to be fired if the free memory down to 100MB. So we are getting a memory critical alert once per day and what we do is just restarting the tomcat server.

Since we are restarting the tomcat not getting `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Yes, there is no issue with the heap, the heap gets cleared if I run a manual GC. But the problem is how the server's free memory decreases to 100MB even there is a restriction of Xmx3072M and the heap is never going to go beyond its limit.

Earlier the Xmx was 2048MB and the heap didn't exceed that level and it gets cleared by the GC. but the tomcat memory consumption continuously growing till getting alerts. And I checked other memory areas related to JVM and nothing found suspicious.

That's why I suspect this should be a java native memory leak (not visible to JVM-related stats).

Comment: Yes, your point is correct. The only reason why we restart before run out of memory is we can't afford any crash or something to happen as this is our production env.

Comment: If it ran fine with `Xmx=2048M`, then the memory leak would've exhibited already. Clearly you don't have a memory leak. You may not enough memory though, as 4GB is ridiculously low for a prod server. Instead of chasing ghosts you should be lowering the `Xmx`, getting more memory, or finding out whether it will run with `Xmx=3G` properly or not by seeing what happens when you ignore nagios.

Comment: I was mentioning that when I ran with `Xmx=2048M` same issue was there (tomcat memory consumption continuously growing till the memory alert at 100MB).  And our application is a microservice and the same application running on 3 nodes with a load balancer. We added another 2 nodes to the cluster and the behavior is the same.

Comment: You should set up a test environment and see if you run out of memory.

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently working on that. Thanks for your support